# What could be the reason for random "Permission denied" when using std::ofstream?

Tags: android, c++, std, ofstream

I have a method that reads two image files, merges them into a new image file and finally removes the two merged image files. This method is called to do that process hundreds of times for different image files.

This process of merging and saving works well but in some cases I get a "Permission denied" when trying to save the merged image. The following code snippet shows how I test for this error.

```
std::ofstream outfile(file, std::ofstream::binary);
if (!outfile.good())
{
    LOGE("Failed to open new file! %s", strerror(errno));
    error = ERROR_FILE_OPEN_FAILED;
}
```

Why could this be? Is it possible that this error happens when multiple threads are overusing file IO?

Comment: It probably means you don't have permission to read the file.  What file are you trying to read/write?  It won't likely be due to multithreading, unless you've exceeded the maximum number of open files and were denied opening any file.  But that number is in the thousands, and you can reclaim them by closing files when you're done with them.  So its unlikely to hit except via a bug.

Comment: Thanks @GabeSechan, well this all happens inside the app sandbox in a Chromebook device. So file access is available for write/read.

Comment: Did you check that your threads are not accidentally generating same file name for the merged image?